# Edited question reloads when clicking 'close', then gives "3 seconds error" after clicking 'close' again

Tags: bug, edits

When a question is edited while it is on your screen, it gets a nice banner:

> an edit has been made to this post; click to load

That's handy, but when I see the question has close-votes or is an obvious duplicate, I'll click 'close' to see the close dialog.

However, clicking the 'close' link below the question in that scenario reloads the question, but it doesn't show the close dialog. Clicking that link again after the reload shows:

[image]

So: I would expect clicking 'close' under a question that was edited after it was displayed in my browser not to reload the question, but show the close dialog instead. Or reload the post, and *not* count the click as a request for the dialog, so I can click it again immediately. Or, ultimately, do both: reload, then show the dialog (it's movable after all, if you want to see whether the edit improved the post).

Of course there's a workaround: click 'close', watch the question reload, wait for three seconds and click 'close' again, but ain't nobody got time for that.